# NullPointerException при считывании данных с клавиатуры

Tags: java, алгоритм, ооп, ввод, scanner

Имеется код:

```
package testPackage;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n;
        System.out.println("Enter size:");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        n = scanner.nextInt();
        Student arr[] = new Student[n];
        for (int i = 0; i<n;i++){
            String temp;
            System.out.println("Enter the ID:");
            scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            temp = scanner.nextLine();
            arr[i].setId(temp);
        }
    }
}

public class Student {
    private String id;
    private String surname;
    private String name;
    private String secondName;
    private String faculty;
    public void setId(String id){
        this.id = id;
    }
    public void setFaculty(String faculty) {
        this.faculty = faculty;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setSecondName(String secondName) {
        this.secondName = secondName;
    }
    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public String getFaculty() {
        return faculty;
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public String getSecondName() {
        return secondName;
    }
    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }
}
```

Задача - заполнение массива данными о студентах. Однако после считывания ID в первый раз выбивает

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   testPackage.Main.main(Main.java:17)

Если что, 17 строка - это             `arr[i].setId(temp);`

В чем ошибка и как ее исправить?

Comment: Вы объявили массив `arr`, но ничем его не заполнили. Поэтому все его элементы равны `null`. Естественно, что попытка вызвать метод на `null` приводит к исключению.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перед 17-ой строкой добавьте `arr[i] = new Student();` Таким образом Вы создадите элемент типа Student и поместите его в i-ый элемент массива.